# Can we set any conditions in kubernetes init containers?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, init

I have a container **X** and it should wait for the container **Y** to start however container **Y** has two modes and the init of **X** should select the mode which is active. how do I set init configuration of **X** to select the active one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you can do very simply is use a `ConfigMap` in your cluster. This `ConfigMap` will have a key that denotes the `mode` you want to use. You will mount this `ConfigMap` in your container `Y`, which serves as an `initContainer` and depending on how it executes it will set the value of `mode` variable in the `ConfigMap`.

Later, when the container `X` starts, it will read the value of this `mode` variable from the `ConfigMap` it will mount as a volume (this can also be imported as an environment variable). This will allow the container `X` to execute based on the `mode` set by container `Y`.